# Have Same Data in 2 VPS

Tags: vps, centos7, cpanel, transfer

I have two VPS that installed WHM on each, I want to have same data on both of them.
Now one of my VPS have data and one of them is empty.
There is any solution to i have all my data, database, emails and everything in my VPS to my another VPS, and update my second VPS when any change occurred on my VPS.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @ceejayoz I try to use Cluster but find this not true solution, also full backup and daily backup is not handle my request

Comment: You haven't answered my question at all. What problem are you trying to solve? Are you trying to have a load-balanced cluster of servers?

Comment: @ceejayoz ow, sorry, i want to have ready to use data in another VPS to use second server when my server goes down (Just with change IP address of my domain NS Records).

Comment: That is not a trivial undertaking. Is this really so frequent you need to devote potentially weeks of work and ongoing maintenance to it? If not, consider a more reliable host.

Comment: The quickest solution is you can use fileserver for data folders

Comment: You still end up with a single point of failure unless you invest heavily in a multi-node NAS or similar

Comment: @ceejayoz I use Interserver VPS and this datacenter is one of the best datacenters and i haven't many issue with this and my websites works fine almost time. but i have important websites in my VPS that not be down at all, so i think this solution maybe help me to reduce my risk.

Comment: If your datacenter is great and reliable, adding this will probably make your site *less* reliable IMO. Clustering solutions are often complex and require ongoing maintenance, as well as pretty decent sysadmin skills. Consider another approach.

Answer (score 6):

I've heard about replication for Linux from StarWind. I'm not sure if it's allowed for right now, but there should be the presentation so you can ask an engineer about it.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/registration-for-the-tap-room